# How to use place holders in tkinter sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a program with a sqlite database and I'm trying to update a record by using place holders. I'm not sure why but I'm getting the following error:  TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
So here is a sample of my code if anyone can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('roominventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM rooms")
    records = c.fetchall()

    for record in records:
        if record[0] == roomget:
            break

    t = ("N",)
    rm = (roomget,)
    c.execute("UPDATE rooms SET vacant = ? WHERE number = ?", t, rm)

    c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tuple`:

```
t = "N"
rm = roomget
c.execute("UPDATE rooms SET vacant = ? WHERE number = ?", (t, rm))
# c.fetchall()  # should not call it here
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I did that and got the following error: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Ok. I made a typo in my code. It actually worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

In your update query, I think if you do like this it should work.

```
t = "N"
rm = roomget
query = "UPDATE rooms SET vacant = ? WHERE number = ?", (t, rm)
c.execute(*query)
# c.fetchall()  # should not call it here
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is because of at the time of executing query it will be parsed and need to unpack the tuple. Let me know if works.